# Build mongodb c++ driver that can use auth method

Tags: mongodb

I wan't to limit mongodb write. So, I add some user on mongodb. But, when I start mongodb with `--auth`, then My Client use auth to connect failed. I get this message:

> caught SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism support not compiled into client library.

I compile c++ driver use `--ssl`. But It does'nt make the Install dir when compile finished. Only have some file and dir like this:

```
build\win32\32\dynamic-boost_off
|
|----mongo(some .obj file)
|----third_party
|----libmongoclient-s.lib
```

I try to use **libmongoclient-s.lib.** But I don't know how to use it. 
Because:

1. Don't have suit head file
2. Compile don't link to libmongoclient-s.lib

Please help me.

some infomation:

**OS**: *Windows*

**VS version**: *visual studio 2013*

*mongodb c++ driver version: mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.0*

compile command:

```
scons --32 --dynamic-boost=off --cpppath="F:\boost_1_59_0" --extrapath="C:\OpenSSL-Win32" -- libpath="F:\\boost_1_59_0\lib32-msvc-12.0"  --ssl --msvc-version=12.0 --dbg=on  --dynamic-windows --sharedclient --prefix="F:\driver" install
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex Weitz。This is my first Question at StackOverflow. I  will do better next time.